# How are action overrides handled for managed package upgrades?

Tags: managed-package, sobject

I want to override a custom object's "New" action with a Visualforce page in my managed package. (This is the mechanism where the platform's default New or Edit or View etc. actions can be routed to custom logic.)

For new installs, that is fine because the default profiles will include the new page. (Unfortunately, we are not using permission sets.) But for upgrades, where customers are using their own profiles, it would be ideal if the override was not applied, to avoid an access denied error after the upgrade. The customer can then manually opt in, including updating their profiles. I see that these overrides can be edited both in the managed package namespace org and in orgs that use the managed package.

Is an action override (newly added to the managed package) ignored in favor of the current action override setting in the org for an upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this by installing a managed package with no action over-rides in it and then upgrading to a package version that had an action over-ride. It looks like the over-ride is applied upon package upgrade. So profiles would have to be manually updated after package upgrade?

Comment: Not good news but good to know up front.